# Windows Mobile Bluetooth connection

Tags: bluetooth, connection, windows-mobile

How could I connect to ActiveSync via Bluetooth while the "Connect via Bluetooth" does not show up in the ActiveSync on my mobile ?

Comment: And you're sure bluetooth is enabled, right?

Comment: yes, I am sure.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Bluetooth is turned on first and then when you go to Activesync from the phone, you should have the `Sync via Bluetooth` option.

If you still don't, try first pairing your phone and computer.